# Intercalate MySQL command with C++ variables

Tags: c++, mysql

I need to intercalate a MySQL command with C++ variables provided by the program to create a query and submit.

I have the following:

```
int source, temperature, humidity, airCo, noise;
char query[500];
```

Attempt #1:

```
sprintf (query, "insert into defaultsensor1 (dateTime, temperature, humidity, airCo, noise) values (now(), " + 
                temperature + ", " + 
                humidity + ", " + 
                airCo + ", " + 
                noise + ")";
```

Attempt #2:

```
 sprintf (query, "insert into defaultsensor1 (dateTime, temperature, humidity, airCo, noise) values (now(), %i, %i, %i, %i)",
                 temperature, 
                 humidity, 
                 airCo, 
                 noise );
```

Attempt #3:

```
sprintf (query, "insert into defaultsensor1 (dateTime, temperature, humidity, airCo, noise) values (now(), %s, %s, %s, %s)", 
                std::to_string(temperature), 
                std::to_string(humidity), 
                std::to_string(airCo), 
                std::to_string(noise));
```

...aaaaaand none worked.

Tutorials on the internet basically revolve around what I tried above. How do I do it?

Comment: In what way did they "not work"? Any error messages?

Comment: What errors did you get when executing the query? Have you tried copying the resulting query string & running in MySQL workbench?

Comment: General tip, when giving table names use back-ticks `\`tablename\`` to avoid keyword clashes. Put string field values in quotes `'stringvalue'`.

Comment: never heard of sql injection?

Comment: @dynamic: as the variables are all integers, exactly how could sql injection be done with the above code?

Comment: @PaulF I don't think it would, but SQL concatenation is still a bad habit to have. Plus, if someone ever changes the types of the variables, it's trouble.

Comment: @luiscubal: depends on the circumstances - I use it a lot in my code - there is no user input at all so no possibility of SQL injection. Exactly how does raising the spectre of "SQL injection" help the OP with his problem?

Comment: @PaulF Presumably, he'll apply the solutions we tell him to other similar problems -- and some of those other problems may involve strings.

Comment: Easy, gentlemen. Let me clarify.

The program will work without user input so SQL Injection won't happen. Also, the application must be written in C++ AND store data generated to a MySQL so it needs to be able to interpolate cpp code and SQL commands.

Comment: @LuisHenrique: Back to my original comment - can you show the actual strings produced in all three attempts. Do you get any error messages.

Comment: @PaulF No, there was no error messages regarding the strings, at lest MySQL didn't returned any in the catch() function. When the program tried to execute the query it crashed and all I got was a 'segmentation violation message' from the simulator. Copying the resulting query string and executing via shell on MySQL works. However, static strings won't work.

Answer (score 2):

General tip, when giving table names use back-ticks `` `tablename` `` to avoid keyword clashes. Put string field values in quotes `'stringvalue'`.

For sql queries I usually us `std::ostringstream` because it automatically converts numbers to strings.

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int source, temperature, humidity, airCo, noise;

    // ... such and so forth ...

    std::ostringstream sql;

    sql << "insert into `defaultsensor1`";
    sql << " (`dateTime`, `temperature`, `humidity`, `airCo`, `noise`)";
    sql << " value ";
    sql << "(now(), " << temperature << ", " << humidity << ", " << airCo << ", " << noise << ")";

    std::cout << "sql: " << sql.str().c_str() << '\n';
}
```

**Note:** The string is extracted from the `std::ostringstream` using `sql.str().c_str()` in order to pass to `MySQL API` calls.

Eg.

```
res = stmt->executeQuery(sql.str().c_str());
```

That converts the `std::ostringstream` to a `std::string` and then into a `const char*` needed for the call.

Comment: Wow, nice code! Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V it and worked flawlessly!

However, when trying to execute the query it returns another error, related to the variable:

`dbWriteLinux.h:71:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘sql::Statement::executeQuery(std::ostringstream&)’
         res = stmt->executeQuery(sql);`

Comment: If you want to see the code, take a look:

[DbWriteLinux.h](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/dbWriteLinux.h)

Comment: @LuisHenrique Use `stmt->executeQuery(sql.str().c_str());`. That converts the `std::ostringstream` to a `std::string` and then into a `const char*` needed for the call.

Comment: Thanks again. It compiles now, but the program now crashes when executing the query. The error it returns is `Simulation terminated with exit code 139` Exit code 139 (128+11) means segmentation violation. Any tips? :/

Comment: @LuisHenrique It could be anything. I suggest you open a new question, posting compilable example code (or a cut down version of your code) that reproduces this error.